# Conveying a message in a club advertisement

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

There has been a dispute between my colleague and I between the use of a phrase in our club advertisement. We are a chemistry interest group and sometimes, I feel that new students may feel that the chemistry we do in the club may be difficult etc. Thus, I would like to add in the club advertisement that the chemistry we learn about is "simple-to-understand". However, my colleague says that the word "simple" puts people off as it makes people think that the chemistry we learn about is too simplistic and boring. This is making me extremely annoyed. So I would like to ask about the effect of the phrase "simple-to-understand" on the reader? Does it make the sentence better or worse, in the eyes of the new student?

Note: The target audience is an incoming batch of new students to the school. This advertisement's purpose is to help the club attract new members. The whole sentence is "... members are able to learn interesting and **simple-to-understand** chemistry outside of the school syllabus".

Comment: I think it's fine as it is, but you could consider "easy-to-understand" which means the same thing but avoids the undesired connotations of "simple"; or try "interesting introductory chemistry".

Comment: how old are you?

Comment: @faustus Is that relevant to my question? Clearly, I am of a school-going age.

Comment: yes. are you a junior or a senior or are you in college and referring to the School of Chemistry?

Comment: @TanYongBoon dude, don't be snarky. i needed to know what your target audience was because that would influence how you phrase things.

Comment: @faustus If you are really that interested... I am a 17-year-old student in my first year at a junior college in Singapore.

Answer (score 1):

*Simple* may be too low brow and Chappo has suggested *easy* and *introductory* as better alternatives.

However to make it more attractive you could argue with your colleague over,

> "... members are able to learn interesting and
>   **[element](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/elementary)ary** chemistry outside of the school syllabus".
>
> "... members are able to learn interesting and
>   **[fun](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fundamental)damental** chemistry outside of the school syllabus".

Comment: Although I feel that "fundamental" has a completely different meaning, I think it sounds good and is able to convey what I have in mind. "Elementary" still makes it sound a bit too "simple". Thanks for the input.

Comment: Oh... I didn't realise that... Yes, the effect of that is quite good!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, simple has a negative overtone. For example, simple things are for simpletons or fools. I do like Chappo’s suggestion easy to understand.

You may also consider, “step by step” conveying a slow, clear and methodical means of instruction.